# Load data from disk into gridview

Tags: c#, file, gridview, hard-drive

How do I load data from the local disk into a gridview?
The data is mp3 files. But text files should be an option too.
And it's not the content of the text file I want, just the file name.
This goes for mp3 files too.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an overview of files in a given directory in a gridview?

Comment: what you need to load whole file or just file's path...

Comment: @MayankPathak, yes i need the whole path of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code :

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("your DriverName://");
dataGridView1.DataSource = di.GetDirectories();
```

or you can use Linq for filter,...

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("your DriverName://")
var query = from p in di.GetDirectories()
            where p.Extension=="*.mp3"
            select new {Name=p.FullName };
 dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

and for get Directory Name:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("your DriverName://");
var query = from p in di.GetDirectories()
            select new { DirectoryName=p.FullName};
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but can this be narrowed down to 'working directory'? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DirectoryInfo` class to view the files in the directory. Then specify a filter and get the collection of required files. Bind gridView's ItemsSource to this collection and override GridView's ItemsTemplate to display items correctly.